# How to break a program when the enter is empty

Tags: java, input

I have a function that, for example, read numbers line by line, and calculates the sum of those numbers.
The user enters the numbers, one number per line, and when enters 'null', the program breaks and give the result.
For example:

`>>8`
`>>5`
`>>4`
`>>`
`The result is 17`

How can I do that the program breaks when the input is empty and give the result?

Comment: apply some flow control: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html

Comment: By testing if the user's input is empty. However, pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch thanks for that. The thing is that I was writting from my cellphone, thats why I couldn't get a good post. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that I thought of using scanner. The comment in the code is where I think you might have messed up on, key areas, and things that you asked.

```
public static void sumInputs(){
    Scanner data=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList <Double> allNumbers=new ArrayList<>();
    while(true){
        System.out.print("Number:");
        try{
            //IMPORTANT: Notice I use "nextLine" and not "next", because next will wait till user inputs something not null
            //and ignours the "enter" key pressed, while "nextLine" executes when the user presses the key "enter" regardless
            //of whether there is input.
            //I would imagine this is your problem
            String number=data.nextLine();

            //The part you are looking for
            //Right here is the part you are looking for
            if(!number.isEmpty()){
                //what to do if it is not null (store the numbers
                //in an ArrayList).
                allNumbers.add(Double.parseDouble(number));
            }else{
                //add up all the numbers if it is null
                double sum = 0;
                for( double i : allNumbers) {
                    sum += i;
                }
                System.out.println("The result is "+ sum);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Not number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
string mystr;
    getline(cin,mystr);
    if(mystr.empty())
//do stuff
    else 
 //do stuff
```

i am sorry i tought this was a c++ question when i saw >> anyway here is the java version

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = scanner.nextLine();
        if(text.isEmpty())
            //do stuff
        else 
            //do stuff
```